# Django: runserver: How to customize the "[DD/MMM/YYYY HH:MM:SS] GET / HTTP/1.1" log statement

Tags: python, django

I am running a django project.

I run the server using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

When i open a page in the browser it outs

```
[13/Jan/2020 08:36:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 298
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[13/Jan/2020 08:36:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2683
```

I want to cutomize this to

```
[13/Jan/2020 08:36:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 298

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
#########################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Not Found: /favicon.ico
[13/Jan/2020 08:36:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2683

$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
#########################################################################
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I want to add some divider lines because many times it gets mixed up

**SOLUTION**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[{asctime}] {message}\n\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n############################################################################################\n@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))\n(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((\n&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\n',
            'datefmt' : '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'style': '{',
            }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'django.server': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'django.server',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.server':{
            'handlers': ['django.server'],
            'propagate': False,
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use your own custom log handler.

Comment: should i use django.request or django.server

Comment: It depends on your requirement.

Comment: I solved it using logging config. Added in the updated question at the bottom. Thanks